# Extract properties from a CRL file using C#

Tags: c#, x509, certificate-revocation

I'd like to write a program which monitors CRL (Certificate Revocation List) expiration date.
Therefore, I'd like to read the following properties from a CRL file:
1) Effective Date
2) Next Update
3) Next CRL Publish

How can I accomplish my task?
I've only managed to find types for X509Certificate2, X509Chain, x509RevocationMode etc..

Comment: What code have you tried already?

Comment: I have tried to look through msdn for documentation about crypto.
Found nothing about parsing CRL files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the class X509Certificate2  to get information needed.

example:To handle one certification file

```
X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2();
byte[] rawData = ReadFile(fname);
x509.Import(rawData);
var validDate= x509 . NotBefore;    
var expireDate = x509.NotAfter;


//Reads a file.
internal static byte[] ReadFile (string fileName)
{
    FileStream f = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    int size = (int)f.Length;
    byte[] data = new byte[size];
    size = f.Read(data, 0, size);
    f.Close();
    return data;
}
```

reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2(v=vs.110).aspx

**Edit:**

You can use the BouncyCastle.Crypto library to handle CRL.
Download the library and reference the BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll
or instal the nuget package:

```
Install-Package BouncyCastle


  //reference library BouncyCastle.Crypto
  //http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/
  //Load CRL file and access its properties
    public void  GetCrlInfo(string fileName, Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger serialNumber, Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buf = ReadFile(fileName);
            X509CrlParser xx = new X509CrlParser();
            X509Crl ss = xx.ReadCrl(buf);
            var nextupdate = ss.NextUpdate;
            var isRevoked = ss.IsRevoked(cert);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",nextupdate,isRevoked);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code will not work for CRL File.It is different from x509 certificate.
NotBefore is a property inside a certificate which implies when the certificate became valid, NotAfter implies when the certificate will expire.

Comment: I edit the post and add code for processing CRL. I hope to be  helper.

Comment: Thank you very much! this library is exactly what I need.

Comment: Welcome. Glad that my post help you.

Comment: the problem of using this, is that it will override the System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates lib.

Answer (score 1):

Although, the question is answered, I would add that there is another good open project that extends native .NET Framework to work with cryptography objects which are missing in the .NET: https://github.com/Crypt32/pkix.net

In regards to CRL, I developed an `X509CRL2` class in a similar way to built-in `X509Certificate2`: [X509CRL2 Class](http://pkix2.sysadmins.lv/library/html/T_System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509CRL2.htm). The usage is pretty simple:

```
// reference System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates namespace
var crl = new X509CRL2(@"C:\temp\crlfile.crl");
// Effective date:
var effective = crl.ThisUpdate;
// next update:
var nextupdate = crl.NextUpdate;
// next publish:
var nextPublishExtension = crl.Extensions["1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.4"];
if (nextPublishExtension != null) { nextPublishExtension.Format(1); }
```

I support CRL files in multiple formats, including pure binary, Base64 or even in hex.

By using this class you can not only read CRL properties, but you can generate Version 2 CRLs.

Note: pkix.net library relies on my another open project https://github.com/Crypt32/Asn1DerParser.NET which is used to parse ASN structures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I find your answer beneficial.  I'll look into using your code.

Comment: How do I use your library? Is there a NuGet package, or do I need to build your DLL manually and include it? I could not find a NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to M.Hassan post ;

Using BouncyCastle.X509 you must convert the System.Security... X509Certificate2 to BouncyCastle certificate, the missing function between initial code and edit could be :

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

public static Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate Convert(X509Certificate2 certificate) 
{
    var certificateParser = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser();
    var rawData = certificate.GetRawCertData();
    var bouncyCertificate = certificateParser.ReadCertificate(rawData);
    return bouncyCertificate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use CertEnroll win32 APIs. The code can be

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(crlFile);
var base64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes); 

CX509CertificateRevocationList crl = new CX509CertificateRevocationList();
crl.InitializeDecode(base64, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64_ANY);
```

Add the following to the csproj for including certEnrol

```
<ItemGroup>
<COMReference Include="CERTENROLLLib">
  <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
  <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
  <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
  <Guid>728ab348-217d-11da-b2a4-000e7bbb2b09</Guid>
  <Lcid>0</Lcid>
  <Isolated>false</Isolated>
  <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
</COMReference>
```